# What is the maximum train dataset limit for training Stanford NER?

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp

I am trying to train a Stanford NER model for 2 new named entities and I have a huge training set available (~300,000 files each around 2k). Is it possible to train this at once? What might be the memory requirements?

Answer (score 0):

There is no maximum per se.  The limit is set by how much memory you have and how fast your CPU is/how long you are willing to wait.

We don't have much data on the largest set anyone has ever used to successfully train a model.  You will have to run experiments to see what is possible given your set up.